# Custom three day view problems

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to adapt fullcalendar to fit a smaller screen (iPhone) and I am trying to create a useful week view by displaying 3 days instead of 7. It is an easy modification to change the columns displayed to 3 days but this causes issues when rendering events. Nothing shows up on the correct day!

Here is the modified source code:

```
function BasicWeekView(element, calendar) {
...
    function render(date, delta) {
        if (delta) {
        addDays(date, delta * 3);
        }
        var start = addDays(cloneDate(date), 3);
        var end = addDays(cloneDate(start), 3);
        var visStart = cloneDate(start);
        var visEnd = cloneDate(end);
        t.title = formatDates(
            visStart,
            addDays(cloneDate(visEnd), -1),
            opt('titleFormat')
        );
        t.start = start;
        t.end = end;
        t.visStart = visStart;
        t.visEnd = visEnd;
        renderBasic(1, 1, 3, false);
    }
}
```

This causes the events to render incorrectly and I'm mystified as to why? I've gone through the source and tried to trace it back to the cause without success. Clicking the day still shows the proper date (via dayClick) so I am out of ideas.

To give a bit more detail on the errors, almost every event renders incorrectly. The third day will often render events in the first day or not at all (ie 1px wide). The second day renders events in the third day and the first in the second. Weekends are handled strangely as well and sometimes when moving to the next date or previous date it will change to day view.

I'm completely baffled and would love some help. I have dug through the api and trolled through the questions on stack exchange without luck... any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The rendering of the events is pretty messed up. Customising fullcalneder is a nightmare- The grid,events and views are all seperate and relative.. arrr

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to do something similar with Full Calendar on Android.
There was an update in version 2.2.5 of Full Calendar that allows this kind of customization.

This can now be done with something like this:

```
views: {
  agendaThreeDay: {
    type: 'agenda',
    duration: { days: 3 },
    buttonText: '3 day'
  },
  defaultView: 'agendaThreeDay'
}
```

Customizing full calendar can still be a nightmare but it's come a long way.
You can get more information on this from the document page on [Custom Views](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/).